# DTTimePeriod conflicting output

Tags: objective-c, ios9, nsdateformatter

I have a startDate of type `DTTimePeriod.StartDate` the value of startDate is

> startDate: 2015-12-31 18:29:59 +0000

when i convert it to string using `NsDateFormatter`

> dateFormat = "d MMM YYY";
>       formatterBehavior = 1040;
>       timeZone = "Asia/Kolkata (GMT+5:30) offset 19800";

when i pass the date to `stringFromDate` method in `NsDateFormatter` the expected output is 31 December 2016 but the output of  `stringFromDate` is 31 December 2016.

Q1. unable to understand the DTTimePeriods startDate property?

Q2. What changes needs to be done to fix the above issue?

Comment: Using the same date, date format, and time zone, I cannot reproduce this problem. I get 1 Jan 2016 instead.

Comment: the expected output is 31 Dec 2015, is it something wrong with date format i am providing??

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your date format is wrong. "YYY" is the year in "week of year" systems and as the [date format standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) says, it "may not always be the same value as calendar year."

You want "yyy", not "YYY".